# Send In Blue : sending mail with attachement to sendinblue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sendinblue

I'm trying to send attachment to **sendinblue** (version 3) using **sendTransacEmail ()** method,
below is my code for Sending a transactional email,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;


import sendinblue.ApiClient;
import sendinblue.ApiException;
import sendinblue.Configuration;
import sendinblue.auth.ApiKeyAuth;
import sibApi.SmtpApi;
import sibModel.CreateSmtpEmail;
import sibModel.SendSmtpEmail;
import sibModel.SendSmtpEmailAttachment;
import sibModel.SendSmtpEmailBcc;
import sibModel.SendSmtpEmailReplyTo;
import sibModel.SendSmtpEmailSender;
import sibModel.SendSmtpEmailTo;

/**
 * Handler for requests to Lambda function.
 */
public class App implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {

    public Object handleRequest(final Object input, final Context context) {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("X-Custom-Header", "application/json");
        try {
            final String pageContents = this.getPageContents("https://checkip.amazonaws.com");
            String output = String.format("{ \"message\": \"hello world\", \"location\": \"%s\" }", pageContents);

            String access_key = "#########";

            ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();
            ApiKeyAuth apiKey = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("api-key");
            apiKey.setApiKey(access_key);

            SmtpApi apiInstance = new SmtpApi();
            Long templateId = 1L; // Long | Id of the template

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("TITLE", "Testing  ,His name");
            params.put("SUBJECT", "Testing This is my subject");

            SendSmtpEmailBcc sendSmtpEmailBcc = new SendSmtpEmailBcc();

            SendSmtpEmailReplyTo sendSmtpEmailReplyTo = new SendSmtpEmailReplyTo();
            sendSmtpEmailReplyTo.setEmail("Testing.123@abcdxyz.com");
            sendSmtpEmailReplyTo.setName("Test-EMailReplyTo");

            SendSmtpEmailTo sendSmtpEmailTo = new SendSmtpEmailTo();
            sendSmtpEmailTo.setEmail("Testing.123@abcdxyz.com");
            sendSmtpEmailTo.setName("sendSmtpEmailTo");

            SendSmtpEmailSender sendSmtpEmailSender = new SendSmtpEmailSender();
            sendSmtpEmailSender.setEmail("Testing.123@abcdxyz.com");
            sendSmtpEmailSender.setName("Test-Sender");


            byte[] bFile = readBytesFromFile("/home/Testing123/Downloads/Testing123.jpg");
            byte[] bArr =Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bFile).getBytes();

            SendSmtpEmail sendSmtpEmail = new SendSmtpEmail();

            SendSmtpEmailAttachment sendSmtpEmailAttachment1 = new SendSmtpEmailAttachment();
            sendSmtpEmailAttachment1.setUrl("/home/Testing123/Downloads/Testing123.jpg");
            sendSmtpEmailAttachment1.setName("My attachment 1");
            sendSmtpEmailAttachment1.setContent(bArr);

            sendSmtpEmail.sender(sendSmtpEmailSender);
            sendSmtpEmail.to(Arrays.asList(sendSmtpEmailTo));
            sendSmtpEmail.replyTo(sendSmtpEmailReplyTo);
            sendSmtpEmail.params(params);
            sendSmtpEmail.templateId(1L);

            //sendSmtpEmail.setAttachment(Arrays.asList(sendSmtpEmailAttachment1));



            System.out.println(sendSmtpEmail);

            CreateSmtpEmail result = apiInstance.sendTransacEmail(sendSmtpEmail);
            System.out.println(result);


            return new GatewayResponse(output, headers, 200);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception when calling SmtpApi#sendTransacEmail");

            e.printStackTrace();
            return new GatewayResponse("{}", headers, 500);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new GatewayResponse("{}", headers, 500);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new GatewayResponse("{}", headers, 500);
        }
    }

    private String getPageContents(String address) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
            return br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        }
    }

}
```

this line giving me Bad Request error ,

```
sendSmtpEmail.setAttachment(Arrays.asList(sendSmtpEmailAttachment1));
```

in the given API https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#sendtransacemail
attachment is an array of objects, in which URL , name & content all are optional.

**how to send email with attachment , 
1. using byte array content ?
2. using url ?**

Answer (score 1):

problem is with this line sendSmtpEmailAttachment1.setName("My attachment 1");

it should be sendSmtpEmailAttachment1.setName("Testing123.jpg"); or any valid extension that allows.